# using a variable inside a batch script for loop instead of file name

Tags: batch-file

hi I'm new to batch scripting when is use address of the of inside the for loop there is no problem
but when is store that address in a variable and use that variable in a for /f loop for loop read the text of the variable not the file content

```
set file1="c:\a.txt"

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (%file1%) DO ( 
    echo %%x
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the quotes in variable value - cmd.exe takes it for a string. Try using `usebackq` and using quotes in set expression like in the example bellow:

```
set "file1=c:\a.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%x in ("%file1%") do (
  echo %%x
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting a filename is a good idea to avoid problems with spaces, but `for /f` processes a quoted string within the parentheses as a literal string, unless you use the `usebackq` option.

Best practice is to quote the string where needed instead of including the quotes to the string, so instead of `set file1="c:\a.txt"`, use `set "file1=c:\a.txt"` (note the position of the quotes).

```
set "file1=c:\a.txt"
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%x in ("%file1%") do (
  echo %%x
)
```